# showing same ad on different button click

Tags: java, android, admob

Excuse my ignorance but I was trying to show an interstitial ad while user clicks on multiple button. I have four buttons and each lead  to different activity. How can I show same ad (without creating extra ad units & variables)  on multiple button click? Here is what I've done so far:

```
        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
                                     {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onAdClosed() {
                                             super.onAdClosed();
                                             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                                             startActivity(intent);
                                         }
                                     }
        );


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onAdClosed` method in Interstitial listener to loadAd again if it's already shown and put `show` funtion on click listeners of the button. I thought four buttons are in the same activity (correct me if I'm wrong)

In your button's onClickListener you used if else statements like `show Ads or Go to this activity` I mean `if unable to show ads then go to this activity, well if the ad was shown to the user then the user will stay at the same activity`.

**Try this :**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
//***This is simple, when the button was clicked Ad will show, also the Activity1 will open.

} else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }});
```

or You should add Interstitial Listener inside the Click listener method of the button, so you can open another activity when Ad was closed.

Comment: @SopnilShah in your button onClickListener you used if else statements like `show Ads or Go to this activity` or `if unable to show ads then go to this activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance of `OnClickListener` like

```
OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

and assign this all button clicks like

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: You wan to show add on each button click.What do you wan to do on adClose?

Comment: yes. i mean if the ad is shown the user has close option. and if the ad is closed it does not go to the activity as specified by intent.

Comment: You mean return back to activity which launched the ad activity

Comment: if that is the case then you need to send activity information in intent and use it to launch the activity again.

Answer (score 0):

onButttonClick show ad like Ratish said

```
OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            position = 1(for first activity)
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            } else{
                nextActivity();
            }
}
```

then on Ad closed do go to next activity do this :

make a String array and store all package names in it and declare an int like :

```
    String optionSelected[] = {"com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.firstActivity", "com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.SecondActivity", "com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.ThirdActivity", "com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.FourthActivity", "com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.fifthActivity", "com.sb.android.acg.upgrade.activity.SixthActivity"};

int position
```

and in `onAdClosed`:

```
 @Override
 public void onAdClosed() {
    super.onAdClosed();
    nextActivity();
}
```

and in `nextActivity`

```
public void nextActivity(){
Intent intent;
        Class<?> aclass = Class.forName(optionSelected[position]);
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, aclass);
         startActivity(intent);
}
```

hope you understood how to call next activity. If any doubt tell me in comment